# Change cursor on mousedown fails with SVG on Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to change the cursor when I drag on a SVG but the cursor change only fires when the mouse button is released. Works perfectly, however, in Firefox.

I'm using Chrome Version 50.0.2661.102 m.

This is the jQuery I'm using:

```
$('#map')
  .mousedown(function(){
    $(this).css( 'cursor', 'move' );
  })
  .mouseup(function(){
    $(this).css( 'cursor', 'auto' );
  });
```

**BUT** the code snippet I added below actually works as it should, yet [the fiddle I created doesn't](http://jsfiddle.net/studiotime/Lyjq6gvd/2/), nor does my actual code on the site I'm building.

How can I do this differently for Chrome so it works always?

```js
var graph = {
 "nodes":[
  {"name":"1","rating":90,"id":2951},
  {"name":"2","rating":80,"id":654654},
  {"name":"3","rating":80,"id":6546544},
  {"name":"4","rating":1,"id":68987978},
  {"name":"5","rating":1,"id":9878933},
  {"name":"6","rating":1,"id":6161},
  {"name":"7","rating":1,"id":64654},
  {"name":"8","rating":20,"id":354654},
  {"name":"9","rating":50,"id":8494},  
  {"name":"10","rating":1,"id":6846874},
  {"name":"11","rating":1,"id":5487},
  {"name":"12","rating":80,"id":"parfum_kenzo"},
  {"name":"13","rating":1,"id":65465465},
  {"name":"14","rating":90,"id":"jungle_de_kenzo"},
  {"name":"15","rating":20,"id":313514},
  {"name":"16","rating":40,"id":36543614},
  {"name":"17","rating":100,"id":"Yann_YA645"},
  {"name":"18","rating":1,"id":97413},
  {"name":"19","rating":1,"id":97414},
  {"name":"20","rating":100,"id":976431231},
  {"name":"21","rating":1,"id":9416},
  {"name":"22","rating":1,"id":998949},
  {"name":"23","rating":100,"id":984941},
  {"name":"24","rating":100,"id":"99843"},
  {"name":"25","rating":1,"id":94915},
  {"name":"26","rating":1,"id":913134},
  {"name":"27","rating":1,"id":9134371}
 ],
 "links":[
  {"source":6,"target":5,"value":6, "label":"publishedOn"},
  {"source":8,"target":5,"value":6, "label":"publishedOn"},
  {"source":7,"target":1,"value":4, "label":"containsKeyword"},
  {"source":8,"target":10,"value":3, "label":"containsKeyword"},
  {"source":7,"target":14,"value":4, "label":"publishedBy"},
  {"source":8,"target":15,"value":6, "label":"publishedBy"},
  {"source":9,"target":1,"value":6, "label":"depicts"},
  {"source":10,"target":1,"value":6, "label":"depicts"},
  {"source":16,"target":1,"value":6, "label":"manageWebsite"},
  {"source":16,"target":2,"value":5, "label":"manageWebsite"},     
  {"source":16,"target":3,"value":6, "label":"manageWebsite"},
  {"source":16,"target":4,"value":6, "label":"manageWebsite"},
  {"source":19,"target":18,"value":2, "label":"postedOn"},
  {"source":18,"target":1,"value":6, "label":"childOf"},
  {"source":17,"target":19,"value":8, "label":"describes"},
  {"source":18,"target":11,"value":6, "label":"containsKeyword"},
  {"source":17,"target":13,"value":3, "label":"containsKeyword"},
  {"source":20,"target":13,"value":3, "label":"containsKeyword"},
  {"source":20,"target":21,"value":3, "label":"postedOn"},
  {"source":22,"target":20,"value":3, "label":"postedOn"},
  {"source":23,"target":21,"value":3, "label":"manageWebsite"},
  {"source":23,"target":24,"value":3, "label":"manageWebsite"},
  {"source":23,"target":25,"value":3, "label":"manageWebsite"},
  {"source":23,"target":26,"value":3, "label":"manageWebsite"}
 ]
}


var margin = {top: -5, right: -5, bottom: -5, left: -5};
        var width = 500 - margin.left - margin.right,
 height = 400- margin.top - margin.bottom;

        var color = d3.scale.category20();
 
 var force = d3.layout.force()
            .charge(-200)
            .linkDistance(50)
            .size([width + margin.left + margin.right, height + margin.top + margin.bottom]);

        var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
            .scaleExtent([1, 10])
            .on("zoom", zoomed);

        var drag = d3.behavior.drag()
            .origin(function(d) { return d; })
            .on("dragstart", dragstarted)
            .on("drag", dragged)
            .on("dragend", dragended);


        var svg = d3.select("#map").append("svg")
            .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
            .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
            .attr("id", "svg")
            .append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.right + ")")
            .call(zoom);

        var rect = svg.append("rect")
            .attr("width", width)
            .attr("height", height)
            .style("fill", "none")
            .style("pointer-events", "all");

        var container = svg.append("g");

//d3.json('http://blt909.free.fr/wd/map2.json', function(error, graph) {
                
                force
                    .nodes(graph.nodes)
                    .links(graph.links)
                    .start();
                
      
     
  var link = container.append("g")
                        .attr("class", "links")
                        .selectAll(".link")
   .data(graph.links)
                        .enter().append("line")
   .attr("class", "link")
   .style("stroke-width", function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.value); });
 
  var node = container.append("g")
                        .attr("class", "nodes")
                        .selectAll(".node")
   .data(graph.nodes)
   .enter().append("g")
   .attr("class", "node")
                        .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
                        .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; })
                        .call(drag);
    
  node.append("circle")
   .attr("r", function(d) { return d.weight * 2+ 12; })
   .style("fill", function(d) { return color(1/d.rating); });
   
                
                force.on("tick", function() {
                    link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
                        .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
                        .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
                        .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

                    node.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });
                });
                
                var linkedByIndex = {};
                graph.links.forEach(function(d) {
                    linkedByIndex[d.source.index + "," + d.target.index] = 1;
                });

                function isConnected(a, b) {
                    return linkedByIndex[a.index + "," + b.index] || linkedByIndex[b.index + "," + a.index];
                }

  node.on("mouseover", function(d){
                        
                        node.classed("node-active", function(o) {
                            thisOpacity = isConnected(d, o) ? true : false;
                            this.setAttribute('fill-opacity', thisOpacity);
                            return thisOpacity;
                        });

                        link.classed("link-active", function(o) {
                            return o.source === d || o.target === d ? true : false;
                        });
                        
                        d3.select(this).classed("node-active", true);
                        d3.select(this).select("circle").transition()
                                .duration(750)
                                .attr("r", (d.weight * 2+ 12)*1.5);
                })
  
  .on("mouseout", function(d){
                        
                        node.classed("node-active", false);
                        link.classed("link-active", false);
                    
                        d3.select(this).select("circle").transition()
                                .duration(750)
                                .attr("r", d.weight * 2+ 12);
                });


        function dottype(d) {
          d.x = +d.x;
          d.y = +d.y;
          return d;
        }

        function zoomed() {
          container.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
        }

        function dragstarted(d) {
          d3.event.sourceEvent.stopPropagation();
          
          d3.select(this).classed("dragging", true);
          force.start();
        }

        function dragged(d) {
          
          d3.select(this).attr("cx", d.x = d3.event.x).attr("cy", d.y = d3.event.y);
          
        }

        function dragended(d) {
          
          d3.select(this).classed("dragging", false);
        }

  $('#map')
    .mousedown(function(){
      $(this).css( 'cursor', 'move' );
    })
    .mouseup(function(){
      $(this).css( 'cursor', 'auto' );
    });
```

```css
.node {
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.node-active{
  stroke: #555;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.link {
  stroke: #555;
  stroke-opacity: .3;
}

.link-active {
  stroke-opacity: 1;
}

.overlay {
  fill: none;
  pointer-events: all;
}

#map{
    border: 2px #555 dashed;
    width:500px;
    height:400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <div id="map"></div>
</body>
```

(sample SVG code borrowed from http://jsfiddle.net/JSDavi/qvco2Ljy/)

Answer (score 2):

If anyone else comes up against this...this was my scenario:

If you have your Chrome inspector open, that is what causes this to fail, if you close the inspector for the page you're creating this effect on, it works perfectly.

Comment: Nope, i did not have inspector open and it did not work.

Comment: Open the inspector on this page and try your code snippet, it fails too

Comment: It also does not work in jsfiddle, both with inspector opened and closed.

Comment: My snippet works here, both with inspector opened and closed. Maybe you have some plugins enabled that screw things up?

Comment: Disabled all extensions and turned off developer mode and still screwed up for me when inspector open.

Comment: Maybe it's a difference of OS, or Chrome version... still, if it stops working only with inspector opened, then it should still be usable for end-users :).

Comment: Happens here as well, Windows 10 x64 and Chrome 66. As soon as I have the DevTools open the cursor doesn't change on mousedown (inside SVG component). Weird!

Answer (score 0):

You have:

```
function dragstarted(d) {
    d3.event.sourceEvent.stopPropagation();

    d3.select(this).classed("dragging", true);
    force.start();
}
```

That call to `stopPropagation` seems to prevent mouse down event. Unfortunately, changing it to `preventDefault` changes how drag&drop works (it moves whole graph around, instead of moving single nodes).

If it is only the cursor you need to change, why not use CSS for that? You already seem to change class of node to `dragging`, so you should be able to simply use following CSS:

```
.node.dragging {
    cursor: move;
}
```

If you want cursor to change also when whole graph is dragged, you can add `dragged` class to the `#map` too:

```
function dragstarted(d) {
    d3.event.sourceEvent.stopPropagation();
    $("#map").addClass("dragging");
    d3.select(this).classed("dragging", true);
    force.start();
}

// ...

function dragended(d) {
    $("#map").removeClass("dragging");
    d3.select(this).classed("dragging", false);
}
```

and then add CSS for that:

```
#map.dragging {
    cursor: move;
}
```

```js
var graph = {
 "nodes":[
  {"name":"1","rating":90,"id":2951},
  {"name":"2","rating":80,"id":654654},
  {"name":"3","rating":80,"id":6546544},
  {"name":"4","rating":1,"id":68987978},
  {"name":"5","rating":1,"id":9878933},
  {"name":"6","rating":1,"id":6161},
  {"name":"7","rating":1,"id":64654},
  {"name":"8","rating":20,"id":354654},
  {"name":"9","rating":50,"id":8494},  
  {"name":"10","rating":1,"id":6846874},
  {"name":"11","rating":1,"id":5487},
  {"name":"12","rating":80,"id":"parfum_kenzo"},
  {"name":"13","rating":1,"id":65465465},
  {"name":"14","rating":90,"id":"jungle_de_kenzo"},
  {"name":"15","rating":20,"id":313514},
  {"name":"16","rating":40,"id":36543614},
  {"name":"17","rating":100,"id":"Yann_YA645"},
  {"name":"18","rating":1,"id":97413},
  {"name":"19","rating":1,"id":97414},
  {"name":"20","rating":100,"id":976431231},
  {"name":"21","rating":1,"id":9416},
  {"name":"22","rating":1,"id":998949},
  {"name":"23","rating":100,"id":984941},
  {"name":"24","rating":100,"id":"99843"},
  {"name":"25","rating":1,"id":94915},
  {"name":"26","rating":1,"id":913134},
  {"name":"27","rating":1,"id":9134371}
 ],
 "links":[
  {"source":6,"target":5,"value":6, "label":"publishedOn"},
  {"source":8,"target":5,"value":6, "label":"publishedOn"},
  {"source":7,"target":1,"value":4, "label":"containsKeyword"},
  {"source":8,"target":10,"value":3, "label":"containsKeyword"},
  {"source":7,"target":14,"value":4, "label":"publishedBy"},
  {"source":8,"target":15,"value":6, "label":"publishedBy"},
  {"source":9,"target":1,"value":6, "label":"depicts"},
  {"source":10,"target":1,"value":6, "label":"depicts"},
  {"source":16,"target":1,"value":6, "label":"manageWebsite"},
  {"source":16,"target":2,"value":5, "label":"manageWebsite"},     
  {"source":16,"target":3,"value":6, "label":"manageWebsite"},
  {"source":16,"target":4,"value":6, "label":"manageWebsite"},
  {"source":19,"target":18,"value":2, "label":"postedOn"},
  {"source":18,"target":1,"value":6, "label":"childOf"},
  {"source":17,"target":19,"value":8, "label":"describes"},
  {"source":18,"target":11,"value":6, "label":"containsKeyword"},
  {"source":17,"target":13,"value":3, "label":"containsKeyword"},
  {"source":20,"target":13,"value":3, "label":"containsKeyword"},
  {"source":20,"target":21,"value":3, "label":"postedOn"},
  {"source":22,"target":20,"value":3, "label":"postedOn"},
  {"source":23,"target":21,"value":3, "label":"manageWebsite"},
  {"source":23,"target":24,"value":3, "label":"manageWebsite"},
  {"source":23,"target":25,"value":3, "label":"manageWebsite"},
  {"source":23,"target":26,"value":3, "label":"manageWebsite"}
 ]
}


var margin = {top: -5, right: -5, bottom: -5, left: -5};
        var width = 500 - margin.left - margin.right,
 height = 400- margin.top - margin.bottom;

        var color = d3.scale.category20();
 
 var force = d3.layout.force()
            .charge(-200)
            .linkDistance(50)
            .size([width + margin.left + margin.right, height + margin.top + margin.bottom]);

        var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
            .scaleExtent([1, 10])
            .on("zoom", zoomed);

        var drag = d3.behavior.drag()
            .origin(function(d) { return d; })
            .on("dragstart", dragstarted)
            .on("drag", dragged)
            .on("dragend", dragended);


        var svg = d3.select("#map").append("svg")
            .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
            .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
            .attr("id", "svg")
            .append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.right + ")")
            .call(zoom);

        var rect = svg.append("rect")
            .attr("width", width)
            .attr("height", height)
            .style("fill", "none")
            .style("pointer-events", "all");

        var container = svg.append("g");

//d3.json('http://blt909.free.fr/wd/map2.json', function(error, graph) {
                
                force
                    .nodes(graph.nodes)
                    .links(graph.links)
                    .start();
                
      
     
  var link = container.append("g")
                        .attr("class", "links")
                        .selectAll(".link")
   .data(graph.links)
                        .enter().append("line")
   .attr("class", "link")
   .style("stroke-width", function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.value); });
 
  var node = container.append("g")
                        .attr("class", "nodes")
                        .selectAll(".node")
   .data(graph.nodes)
   .enter().append("g")
   .attr("class", "node")
                        .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
                        .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; })
                        .call(drag);
    
  node.append("circle")
   .attr("r", function(d) { return d.weight * 2+ 12; })
   .style("fill", function(d) { return color(1/d.rating); });
   
                
                force.on("tick", function() {
                    link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
                        .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
                        .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
                        .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

                    node.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });
                });
                
                var linkedByIndex = {};
                graph.links.forEach(function(d) {
                    linkedByIndex[d.source.index + "," + d.target.index] = 1;
                });

                function isConnected(a, b) {
                    return linkedByIndex[a.index + "," + b.index] || linkedByIndex[b.index + "," + a.index];
                }

  node.on("mouseover", function(d){
                        
                        node.classed("node-active", function(o) {
                            thisOpacity = isConnected(d, o) ? true : false;
                            this.setAttribute('fill-opacity', thisOpacity);
                            return thisOpacity;
                        });

                        link.classed("link-active", function(o) {
                            return o.source === d || o.target === d ? true : false;
                        });
                        
                        d3.select(this).classed("node-active", true);
                        d3.select(this).select("circle").transition()
                                .duration(750)
                                .attr("r", (d.weight * 2+ 12)*1.5);
                })
  
  .on("mouseout", function(d){
                        
                        node.classed("node-active", false);
                        link.classed("link-active", false);
                    
                        d3.select(this).select("circle").transition()
                                .duration(750)
                                .attr("r", d.weight * 2+ 12);
                });


        function dottype(d) {
          d.x = +d.x;
          d.y = +d.y;
          return d;
        }

        function zoomed() {
          container.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
        }

        function dragstarted(d) {
          d3.event.sourceEvent.stopPropagation();
          $("#map").addClass("dragging");
          d3.select(this).classed("dragging", true);
          force.start();
        }

        function dragged(d) {
          
          d3.select(this).attr("cx", d.x = d3.event.x).attr("cy", d.y = d3.event.y);
          
        }

        function dragended(d) {
          $("#map").removeClass("dragging");
          d3.select(this).classed("dragging", false);
        }
```

```css
.node {
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.node.dragging,
#map.dragging {
  cursor: move;
}

.node-active{
  stroke: #555;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.link {
  stroke: #555;
  stroke-opacity: .3;
}

.link-active {
  stroke-opacity: 1;
}

.overlay {
  fill: none;
  pointer-events: all;
}

#map{
    border: 2px #555 dashed;
    width:500px;
    height:400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <div id="map"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Please also see my answer below - weird!

Comment: I've updated answer with suggestion for changing cursor on whole map.

Comment: For changing cursor while dragging whole graph, class manipulation of `#map` should be added somewhere else, because `dragstarted` and `dragended` are not called currently when dragging starts outside of one of nodes.

Comment: @DarrenSweeney I've tried this with codepen, ahway is right about the stopPropagation. the sourceEvent is blocked here so your mousedown never gets executed